# do we have base64 utility for windows like json jq

Tags: base64, window

I am on windows and I can see we have `json jq` utility available. I have downloaded it (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and sets as environment variables, all good.

Do we have similar stuff for `base64` on windows, currently it's giving error like for below command,

```
 k get secret my-user -n elastic-system -o json | jq -r .data.elastic | base64 -D
```

> The term 'base64' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program